# redis: ReplyError: ERR DB index is out of range

Tags: docker, redis, redis-server

I ran redis using Docker like so:

```
docker run  --rm -p '6379:6379' -v "$redis_data_dir:/data" --name my_redis_server -d redis redis-server --appendonly 'yes'
```

in the past this worked fine, but now I get this error:

> ```
> { ReplyError: ERR DB index is out of range
>     at parseError (/root/interos/repos/ntrs-cli/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
>     at parseType (/root/interos/repos/ntrs-cli/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14)
> ```
>
> command: { name: 'select', args: [ '20127' ] } }

It looks like it's trying to connect to db `20127`, I am certain it's one of these four:

```
const client_db0 = new Redis(`redis://${conf["platform-build.public-dns"]}:6379/0`);
const client_db1 = new Redis(`redis://${conf["platform-build.public-dns"]}:6379/1`);
const client_db2 = new Redis(`redis://${conf["platform-build.public-dns"]}:6379/2`);
const client_db3 = new Redis(`redis://${conf["platform-build.public-dns"]}:6379/3`);
```

so is there some way to start redis up and tell it to add more databases? something like:

```
docker run  .... redis redis-server --appendonly 'yes' --db-count=16
```

Answer (score 10):

in file `etc/redis/redis.conf`
change line `databases 16` (by default, it has 16), most likely you need more than 16

by default, each DB index is responsible for 8 or 10 databases (don't remember), so by default you use only 2 indexes (0 and 1)

Answer (score 3):

The `SELECT` command is used to pick which database you're using. 20127 is *way* beyond your configured limit of 16.

Either change `databases` in `/etc/redis.conf` to be higher, which is probably a bad idea for very large values like 20K, or pick a value in the range 0..15.

If you're not sure where 20127 is coming from, track it down in the originating code or configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It was due to the extra whitespace that I had here:

```
 'platform-build.public-dns': ' 127.0.0.1'
```

Maybe the parser could be improved?

Comment: It's usually not the job of the config tool to trim extraneous spaces, so it's just garbage-in, garbage-out.

Comment: Could throw a parsing error tho, instead of completely misinterpreting it

Answer (score 0):

When i stop my docker environment and execute

```bash
docker volume prune
```

Error `ERR DB index is out of range (Redis::CommandError)` dissapears.